# ParametricPlot3D colorfunction for a specific region of an object

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, color

I have created a 3D parametric plot of an oblate spheroid, and I want to apply "TemperatureMap" as a colorfunction to its surface as a gradient in the Z direction. However, I only want to apply this coloring to part of the spheroid, and to color the rest of it gray. I am attempting this by first plotting a gray spheroid, and then overlaying that object with part of another spheroid, which should be colored. Here here is my attempt:

```
rx=2.53*10^9;
ry=2.375*10^9;
rz=8.65*10^8;
Req=1.46*10^9;
obl=0.19;
a=4.4879*10^9;

grayplot=ParametricPlot3D[Req/Sqrt[Sin[θ]^2+Cos[θ]^2/(1-obl)^2]*{Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ],Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ],Cos[θ]},{ϕ,0,2π},{θ,0,π},
    Mesh->None,
    ColorFunction->Function[{x,y,z},Glow[Darker[Gray, 0.4]]],
    ColorFunctionScaling->False,
    Boxed->False,
    Axes->False,
    PlotPoints->35,
    Lighting->{{"Point",White,{0,0,0}}}
];

colorplot=ParametricPlot3D[(Req*1.02)/Sqrt[Sin[θ]^2+Cos[θ]^2/(1-obl)^2]*Boole[rx*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ]+ry*Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ]+rz*Cos[θ]>=Req/Sqrt[Sin[θ]^2+Cos[\Theta]]^2/(1-obl)^2]]*{Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ],Sin[\Phi]]*Sin[θ],Cos[θ]},{ϕ,0,2π},{θ,0,π},
    ColorFunction->Function[{θ},If[θ<π/2,Glow@ColorData[{"TemperatureMap",{0,Req}}][#3]&},{Glow@       ColorData[{"TemperatureMap",{-Req,0}}]}]],
    ColorFunctionScaling->False,
    Mesh->None,
    PlotPoints->24
];

planetgraphic=Graphics3D[{Blue,Sphere[{rx, ry, rz},7.15*10^9]}];

Show[{grayplot,colorplot,planetgraphic},
    ViewPoint->{10,0,0},
    ViewAngle->1/8,
    ViewVertical->{1, 0, 0},
    Boxed->False,
    ImageSize->600,
    Background->Black,
    PlotRange->{{-1.1 a, 1.1 a}, {-1.1 a, 1.1 a},{-1.1 a, 1.1 a}}]
```

rx, ry, rz, and a, are all just constants based on my system. Req is the equatorial radius and obl is the spheroid's oblateness factor.

This code produces [image: bad graphic]. What I want is something like this [image: good graphic]

which I colored by plotting thousands of individual points in Graphic3D (highly inefficient). Basically, I want to recreate that image but with a nice smooth parametric plot. I want the temperature gradient to scale from equator to pole for whatever region of the object I have colored in.

There is an obvious current problem with the lighting in the first image (which is why the colored region is black), but even beyond that the `ColorFunction` in the colorplot is not working properly. If I turn on ambient lighting, the "colored region" is just pure white.

Comment: For clarity, can you give the specific ranges where your surface should be gray, and where it should have the color gradient?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to explain. The colorplot is limited by the Boole function in the main argument. The (phi,theta) that satisfy the inequality inside of that Boole function describe the region that I want colored.

Comment: What do you mean by Z- direction. IN Oblate Spheroidal coordinate is a true 3D curvilinear system.  You might be interested in this post. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149401/sphericalplot3d-of-an-oblatespheroid-via-coordinate-transformation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The case in hand

I would use [`MeshShading`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html) and create a single, unified graphic.

```
With[{ϕ0 = .5,
  rx = 2.53*10^9,
  ry = 2.375*10^9,
  rz = 8.65*10^8,
  Req = 1.46*10^9,
  obl = 0.19}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Req/Sqrt[Sin[θ]^2 + 
      Cos[θ]^2/(1 - obl)^2]*{Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
    Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, 0, 
   2 π}, {θ, 0, π}, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ}, 
    Glow@ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", Req {0, 1}}][Req - Abs@z]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, 
      z, ϕ, θ}, (rx*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ] + 
        ry*Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ] + rz*Cos[θ]) - (Req/
        Sqrt[Sin[θ]^2 + Cos[θ]^2/(1 - obl)^2])]},
  Mesh -> {{0}},
  MeshShading -> {Glow[Darker[Gray, 0.4]], Automatic},
  PlotPoints -> 35, Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {0, 0, 0}}}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can coordinate the [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) and [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) settings to create just about any combination of shaded and colored regions.

---

#### Update: Further remarks on the use of `Mesh` etc.

Note that FEM and mesh regions are different and newer than `Mesh` and its related options of plotting.  Conceptually they are related, but functionally within *Mathematica* they don't seem closely related.

**Basic idea.**
For each mesh function `mf`, a set of values is prescribed or automatically chosen by *Mathematica*, according to option [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html).  (See [`MeshFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunction.html) for a description of the arguments, which are different for each plotter.)  A line is drawn on the surface `mf == c` for each value `c` in the set. This will divide the surface up to regions, which will be colored according to the settings of [`MeshShading`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html) and other style options appropriate to the plotter.  The value of `MeshShading` should be an array of depth equal to the number of mesh functions.

There are two special settings for a `MeshShading` entry: `Automatic` renders the surface according to the other styling directives.  `None` means that no surface will be render (there will be a hole).

It is sometimes important to realize that the mesh lines are created by linearly interpolating along the boundaries of the polygons of the surface constructed by the plotter.  If the numerical accuracy of the mesh lines is important, then it usually has to be addressed via [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html).  The option [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html) may help, but only accidentally: The criteria for recursive subdivision depend on the curvature of the surface and not on the curvature of the mesh lines.

**One mesh function.**
If a single mesh function is used, then the surface will be divided up into bands/stripes and possibly concentric annuli, depending on the function.  The value of `MeshShading` should be of array-depth 1, that is, a simple, flat list.  If $c_1, c_2,\dots$ form the set of mesh values, then regions for which the mesh function has a value less than $c_1$ are given the first color, those for which the value is between $c_1$ and $c_2$ are given the second color, and so on.  The cycle around to the beginning when the end of the list is reached.  If, say, `dir` is a list of `4` graphics directives and there are five mesh values, then `MeshShading -> dir` would color the surface according to the following scheme:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Example:  Note that when the shading is `Automatic`, the `PlotStyle` texture colors the plot; when it is none, the white background shows through.

```
ParametricPlot[{u , v + (u - u^2)/4}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]]},
 Mesh -> 7, MeshShading -> {Automatic, Red, None}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, u, v}, u]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Two mesh functions.**
The remarks about one mesh function still apply, except that the value of `MeshShading` should be of array depth 2 (i.e. a matrix), and the surface will usually be divided up into polygons with curved boundaries.  If we have `MeshShading -> dir`, then when the first mesh function increases past a mesh value, the color will change from `dir[[i, j]]` to `dir[[i + 1, j]]`; when the second mesh function passes a mesh value, the color will change from `dir[[i, j]]` to `dir[[i, j + 1]]`. Of course the indices will wrap around when the corresponding edge of the matrix is reached.

Example.  Suppose `MeshShading` is set to

```
MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Red}, {Blue, Pink}, {Lighter@Blue, None}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then we get, for the default mesh functions, `u` and `v`:

```
ParametricPlot[{u , v + (u - u^2)/4}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]]},
 Mesh -> {5, 4}, 
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Red}, {Blue, Pink}, {Lighter@Blue, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since `v` increases as you go up the image, the colors appear reversed (top to bottom) from how they appear in the matrix rows.

**More mesh functions.**
As the number of functions and depth of the array `dir` of directives in `MeshShading` increases, things get more complicated, but they work in the same way.  When a mesh function crosses a boundary value, the corresponding index in

```
dir[[i1, i2, i3, ...]]
```

changes.  It is rare that one needs to consider this case though.

**Complicated mesh functions.**
The complicated pattern produced in the plot on the left below by the mesh functions

```
mf1 = Function[{x, y, u, v}, Cos[5 x] - y];
mf2 = Function[{x, y, u, v}, x - Cos[5 y]];
```

is hard to describe.  However by plotting each mesh function, we can see where it crosses the different mesh values by *Mathemetica* automatically for the settings of `Mesh` to `5` and `4` respectively.

One can also observe in the lighter blue region below the eye (around the vertex of the cosine minimum), the effect of linear interpolation.  To get a less jagged appearance, increase `PlotPoints`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot[{u , v + (u - u^2)/4}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]]},
 Mesh -> 5,
 MeshFunctions -> {mf1, mf2},
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Red}, {Blue, Pink}, {Lighter@Blue, None}}]

ParametricPlot3D[{u , v + (u - u^2)/4, mf1[u , v + (u - u^2)/4, u, v]},
 {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]]},
 Mesh -> 5,
 MeshFunctions -> {mf1},
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Red}, {Blue, Pink}, {Lighter@Blue, None}}[[2, All]],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.6}]

ParametricPlot3D[{u , v + (u - u^2)/4, mf2[u , v + (u - u^2)/4, u, v]},
 {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]]},
 Mesh -> 5,
 MeshFunctions -> {mf2},
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Red}, {Blue, Pink}, {Lighter@Blue, None}}[[All, 2]], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.6}]
```

Comment: This didn't come to me as I don't think about mesh, not intimately familiar with it. Here you seem to use it like a second color function but I normally just think of it as those grid lines on top of a 3d graphic. I know it is intimately connected with the new region functions as well. Do you know of a resource where I could learn more about what a mesh **is**? Sorry for the vague question lol

Comment: @JasonB I mean to expand my answer at some point to explain what's going on here. I just don't have time today. I figured it out the hard way, by playing with the examples in the docs.  Basically, each time a `Mesh` value is crossed, the position in the `MeshShading` array shifts one (and cycles around to the beginning if the end is reached).

Comment: @JasonB I added some :) explanation.  AFAIK, it's not explained in the documentation, except from what you can infer from examples.

Comment: Thanks again for the lesson on `MeshShading`, as soon as I saw [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114268/9490) question, I knew this was the method to use.

Answer (score 2):

You were mixing your pure function definition types in your `ColorFunction`.  The safest way to make a color function for a `ParametricPlot3D` is of the form `Function[{x,y,z,phi,theta},......]` - you had a `Function[{theta}, ....#3 &...]` in which you wanted the `#3` to apply to the `z` coordinate.

```
rx = 2.53*10^9;
ry = 2.375*10^9;
rz = 8.65*10^8;
Req = 1.46*10^9;
obl = 0.19;
a = 4.4879*10^9;

grayplot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   Req/Sqrt[
      Sin[θ]^2 + Cos[θ]^2/(1 - obl)^2]*{Cos[ϕ]*
      Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
     Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π},
       Mesh -> None,
       ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Glow[Darker[Gray, 0.4]]],
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
       Boxed -> False,
       Axes -> False,
       PlotPoints -> 35,
       Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {0, 0, 0}}}
   ];

colorplot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[(Req*1.02)/
     Sqrt[Sin[θ]^2 + Cos[θ]^2/(1 - obl)^2]*
    Boole[rx*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ] + 
       ry*Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ] + rz*Cos[θ] >= 
      Req/Sqrt[
        Sin[θ]^2 + Cos[θ]^2/(1 - obl)^2]]*{Cos[ϕ]*
      Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
     Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π},
       PlotRange -> Charting`get3DPlotRange@grayplot,
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ},
     Glow@ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {Req, 0}}][Abs@z]],
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
       Mesh -> None,
       PlotPoints -> 100
   ];

Show[{grayplot, colorplot},
     ViewPoint -> {10, 0, 0},
     ViewAngle -> 1/8,
     ViewVertical -> {1, 0, 0},
     Boxed -> False,
     ImageSize -> 600,
     Background -> Black,
     PlotRange -> {{-1.1 a, 1.1 a}, {-1.1 a, 1.1 a}, {-1.1 a, 1.1 a}}]
```

I left out `planetgraphics` as it isn't relevant to the question at hand, and I increased the number of `PlotPoints` in the `colorplot` to get a less jagged edge.

[image]

In fixing the color function, I may have changed it to something different than what you were looking for.  The syntax you had in the third argument to the `If` is confusing, so let me know if you wanted something different.

I think you could get all this out of one plot, if you just make the color function a little more complicated so as to incorporate your `Boole` conditions,

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  Req/Sqrt[Sin[θ]^2 + Cos[θ]^2/(1 - obl)^2]*{Cos[ϕ]*
        Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
   Cos[θ]}, {ϕ,
     0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π},
      Mesh -> None,
      ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ},
      If[rx*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ] + ry*Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ] + 
            rz*Cos[θ] >= 
          Req/Sqrt[Sin[θ]^2 + Cos[θ]^2/(1 - obl)^2],
        Glow@ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {Req, 0}}][Abs@z],
        Glow[Darker[Gray, 0.4]]
        ]
      ], PlotPoints -> 300,
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
      Boxed -> False,
      Axes -> False,
      Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {0, 0, 0}}}, 
    ViewPoint -> {10, 0, 0},
      ViewAngle -> 1/8,
      ViewVertical -> {1, 0, 0},
      Boxed -> False,
      ImageSize -> 600,
      Background -> Black,
      PlotRange -> {{-1.1 a, 1.1 a}, {-1.1 a, 1.1 a}, {-1.1 a, 
    1.1 a}}]
```

But I had to set the `PlotPoints` to a very high level to get a decent output, and it still isn't as good as the plot above,

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I wish I could divide the bounty between you and the answer below. However, that other answer is the method that I will actually use. This was a great answer though!