# Paint a region with different color in ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

```
surface[x_, y_, z_] := Piecewise[{{(x - 1/2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 
  1/16, (x - 1/2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1/16 <= 0 && z >= 0}}, z];   
ContourPlot3D[{surface[x, y, z] == 0},
            {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -0.1, 0.3},
            PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5, 1.5}},
            ImageSize -> 600,
            BoundaryStyle -> None,
            Mesh -> None,
            ViewPoint -> {2, -6, 2}                                                 
            ]
```

The plot is like below. Then I want to paint the region constrained by

```
320x^2-304x+256y^2+57>=0 && 15x^2-16x+19y^2+3<=0
```

with Black color, and the rest area is Orange.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works without making 2 plots and combining them with `Show`, and it also doesn't require using excessive `PlotPoints`.

I'm not sure why `MeshShading` works better in this case than `ColorFunction`, but it does.  Read Michael E2's excellent explanation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108227/9490).

The key points are

1. Set the value of `Mesh` to a single number, 0
2. Set the `MeshFunctions` to the two polynomials which you want to be less than and greater than 0, the number you set already.
3. Set the values for `MeshShading`, giving two values for each `MeshFunction`, either `Automatic` or `Black`, for regions above and below the value of `Mesh`

```
surface[x_, y_, z_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(x - 1/2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 
      1/16, (x - 1/2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1/16 <= 0 && z >= 0}}, z];
ContourPlot3D[{surface[x, y, z] == 0},
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -0.1, 0.3},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5, 1.5}},
 ImageSize -> 600,
 BoundaryStyle -> None,
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 ViewPoint -> {2, -6, 2},
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, 
    320 x^2 - 304 x + 256 y^2 + 57], 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 15 x^2 - 16 x + 19 y^2 + 3]},
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Black}, {Black, Automatic}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This doesn't take any longer than the plotting command in the OP.

Comment: `ColorFunction`, I believe, uses `VertexColors` to apply a color to a vertex of the polygonal mesh that makes the surface of the plot.  The vertex colors are interpolated over the interior of a given polygon.  The result tends to be blotchy, unless the polygons are very small, and to be computationally somewhat more expensive (in the FE/graphics rendering).  Neither `ColorFunction` nor `MeshFunctions` factor into mesh refinement, AFAIK, so boundaries in each method are sometimes not smooth.

Answer (score 1):

```
cp1 = ContourPlot3D[{surface[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
   1}, {z, -0.1, 0.3}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5, 1.5}}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  ContourStyle ->  Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]],
  BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> {2, -6, 2},
  RegionFunction ->  Function[{x, y, z}, 320 x^2 - 304 x + 256 y^2 + 57 <=0|| 
 15 x^2 - 16 x + 19 y^2 + 3>= 0]];

cp2 = ContourPlot3D[{surface[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
   1}, {z, -0.1, 0.3}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5, 1.5}}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, ContourStyle -> Black,
  RegionFunction ->  Function[{x, y, z}, 320 x^2 - 304 x + 256 y^2 + 57 >= 0 && 
     15 x^2 - 16 x + 19 y^2 + 3 <= 0], 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> {2, -6, 2}];

Show[cp1, cp2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can it be written in one ContourPlot3D?

Comment: @QiZhong, maybe using `ColorFunction`. I will post an update if i can make it work.

Comment: Thank you. This method is good enough. But there are two problems. First, two ContourPlot3D means the computer needs to do the calculation twice, which needs almost twice time. Second, the intersection region shows part orange, part black when rotating the figure, because there are two layers there. That's why I want to use only one ContouPlot3D.

Comment: @QiZhong, for  the second issue, use `RegionFunction -> 
 Function[{x, y, z, f}, 
  320 x^2 - 304 x + 256 y^2 + 57 <= 0 || 
   15 x^2 - 16 x + 19 y^2 + 3 >= 0],` in `cp1`.

Comment: @kglr I failed to get anything useful from `ColorFunction`, have you succeeded that way?

Comment: @BlacKow, me neither. Also tried using `{ConditionalExpression[surface[x,y,z], Not@cond]==0, ConditionalExpression[surface[x,y,z], cond]==0}` as the first argument of `ContourPlot3d` but got a messy output.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this,  but the edge is not uniform. You can add x>=3/8 in cp2. Then there is no black area on the left side of the sphere in your figure, but it is empty, shows no color.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `ColorFunction` and `ColorFunctionScaling`.

With

```
region = 320 x^2 - 304 x + 256 y^2 + 57 >= 0 && 15 x^2 - 16 x + 19 y^2 + 3 <= 0
```

Then

```
ContourPlot3D[{surface[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -0.1, 0.3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5, 1.5}}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, 
 ViewPoint -> {2, -6, 2},
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, If[region, Black, Orange]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can increase the `PlotPoints` for a sharper boundary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, it can work. I need to increase PlotPoints to 40 and MaxRecursion->1. It takes ~5minutes. Is it possible to use plotpoints->20 in the x<0 region and plotpoints0>40 in x>0 region?