# Is it possible to achieve the coordinates of the section ClipPlane given?

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

I using the `ClipPlanes` to achieve a section, the code as below:

```
Show[
 {Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 5}, {0, 0, 20}}, 15]], 
  ParametricPlot3D[
    {(10 + 5 Sin[β]) Cos[θ], (10 + 5 Sin[β]) Sin[θ], 5 (1 - Cos[β])}, 
    {β, 0, π/2}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> None], 
  Graphics3D[
    Polygon[CirclePoints[10, 50] /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, 0}]]},
  ClipPlanes -> {{0, -Sin[20 \[Degree]], Cos[20 \[Degree]], -2}}, 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {7, 0, 0}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

However, for the coordinate of the section, I have no idea.

[image]

So I would like to know:

- Is there a workaround to achieve the coordinate of section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the intersection between your surface and a plane defined by

```
{0, -Sin[20 °], Cos[20 °], -2}.{x, y, z, 1} == 0
```

One way to get the intersection points is to use `MeshFunctions` to create a line and then use `Cases` to extract the line:

```
eqn = {0, -Sin[20 °], Cos[20 °], -2}.{x, y, z, 1};
meshopts = 
  {Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, eqn]}, 
   MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}};
plot = Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[
   {15 Cos[th], 15 Sin[th], z}, 
   {th, 0, 2 π}, {z, 5, 20}, Evaluate@meshopts], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
   {r Cos[th], r Sin[th], 0}, 
   {th, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, 10}, Evaluate@meshopts],
 ParametricPlot3D[
   {(10 + 5 Sin[β]) Cos[θ], (10 + 5 Sin[β]) Sin[θ], 5 (1 - Cos[β])}, 
   {β, 0, π/2}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Evaluate@meshopts],
 PlotRange -> {{-16, 16}, {-16, 16}, {-1, 21}},
 ClipPlanes -> {{0, -Sin[20 °], Cos[20 °], -2}}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False
]
```

[image]

Notice the line follows the `ClipPlanes` exactly.

```
points = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity]~Flatten~1;

Graphics3D@Point@points
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit

Above I chose to show your `Cylinder` as a `ParametricPlot3D` because I like the look better.  But if you still want to use a `Cylinder`, then you need to visualize it with some plotting program that takes `MeshFunction` options, and `Graphics3D` and `Show` do not.  This works:

```
plot = Show[
  RegionPlot3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 5}, {0, 0, 20}}, 15], 
   Evaluate@meshopts], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{(10 + 5 Sin[β]) Cos[θ], (10 + 
       5 Sin[β]) Sin[θ], 5 (1 - Cos[β])}, {β,
     0, π/2}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Evaluate@meshopts],
  PlotRange -> {{-16, 16}, {-16, 16}, {-1, 21}}, 
  ClipPlanes -> {{0, -Sin[20 °], Cos[20 °], -2}}, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False
  ]
```

[image]

and you can extract the points in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your `MeshFunctions` strategy, but I would like know: is it possible to smooth the section that achieved with help of `MeshFunctions`.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG - I don't follow, what are you looking to smooth?

Comment: like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GOnDO.png)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG - if you are using the first plot above then you can get better results by setting `PlotPoints->100` in the `ParametricPlot3D` calls.  `RegionPlot3D` is just awful though, so you can't get great results there.

Comment: If I use the higher plotpoints setting, then run the command:  `points = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity];
Graphics[Line /@ points[[All, All, ;; 2]]]` I get this:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/7xuTv.png

Comment: Hi, JasonB, could you give me a explanation about `MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, eqn]}`? I would like to know how does it work. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: It's almost time for me to go home for the day, but I learned everything I know about MeshFunctions from MichaelE2 here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108227/9490